# Stein Real Analysis Theorem 1.4.3: Appximate measurable functions by step functions

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then there exists a sequence of step functions $\{\psi_k\}$ that converges pointwise to $f(x)$ for almost every $x$.
> *Part of the Proof.* By the previous result, it suffices to show that if $E$ is a measurable set with finite measure, then $f=\chi_E$ can be approximated by step functions.

Why?

*Previous result*

> Suppose $f$ is measurable on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Then there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{\phi_k\}$ that converges to $f$ pointwise.

If for $n=1,2,\dots,N$, $\{\psi^n_k\}$ is a sequence of step functions converging to $\chi_{E_n}$, then
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum^N_{n=1}a_n\psi^n_k=\sum^N_{n=1}a_n\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\psi^n_k=\sum^N_{n=1}a_n\chi_{E_n}\text{,}$$
which means that any simple function can be approximated by step functions. By how about general measurable functions? We don't have uniform convergence now, so we cannot choose $k$ such that $|\phi_n(x)-\psi(x)^n_k|<1/k$ and $|f(x)-\psi^n_k(x)|\leq|f(x)-\phi_n(x)|+|\phi_n(x)-\phi^n_{k}(x)|<1/n+1/k$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is genuine and you cannot do this point-wise. You have to bring in some metric to achieve this.

Let $\Delta_j= \{x \in \mathbb R^{d}: \|x\|\leq j\}$. If we find step functions $g_n$ such that $\int_{\Delta_j} \min \{1, |f-g_n|\} dm \to 0$ (where $m$ is Lebesgue measure)  then can extract a subsequence $(g_{n_k})$ for which  $\min \{1, |f-g_{n_k}|\}$ tends to $0$ and this implies $g_{n_k} \to f$ a.e..  on $\Delta_j$ for each $j$, hence we can find a diagonal sequence which converges to $f$ a.e. on $\mathbb R^{d}$.

Find a simple function $h_n$ such that  $\int_{\Delta_j} \min \{1, |f-h_n|\} dm <\frac 1 n$ and then  a step function $g_n$ such that $\int_{\Delta_j} \min \{1, |h_n-g_n|\} dm <\frac 1 n$. [These are possible by DCT. This is where  we want to bring in $\Delta_j$ which has finite measure].  Can you finish?